# How can I change the background color of a button WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi, button, colors, background

I have searched this many times, but everything I find is MFC.  I want it in C++ WinAPI.  I know how to change the style of a button control, but I cannot find out how to make a button a different color.  So, how can I change the background color of a WinAPI button control using C++?  I don't want to do this with a resource file.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set win32 api c++ button background color and text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302850/how-to-set-win32-api-c-button-background-color-and-text-color)

Comment: @RogerRowland That is using resource files.  I want to use all c++ code.

Comment: I think that the answers to that question are all relevant to you - the fact that the question used resource files doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The main thing I was hoping for it be explained a little better too.

Comment: @Roger Rowland: you suggested possible duplicate question but with wrong answer?... LOL

Comment: @dns Well, [as it says here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) *"The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place."*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of a link I'll just post a copy from my other post using custom-drawing, similar to `alwayslearningnewstuff` example:

[image: Nothing is selected]
[image: First button is selected and was pushed]
[image: Second button was pushed and the mouse is over it (notice the increse of brightness - cutom hilight)]

First picture shows when nothing is selected, second shows when first button is selected and was pushed and the last one shows when second button was pushed and the mouse is over it (notice the increase of brightness - cutom hilight). In order to do this, you must catch NM_CUSTOMDRAW message and paint button yourself. And this is how you do it. Also added gradient brush function and some comments.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>

#define IDC_EXIT_BUTTON 101
#define IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON 102

HBRUSH CreateGradientBrush(COLORREF top, COLORREF bottom, LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item)
    {
        HBRUSH Brush = NULL;
        HDC hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(item->hdc);
        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(item->hdc, item->rc.right-item->rc.left, item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top);
        SelectObject(hdcmem, hbitmap);

        int r1 = GetRValue(top), r2 = GetRValue(bottom), g1 = GetGValue(top), g2 = GetGValue(bottom), b1 = GetBValue(top), b2 = GetBValue(bottom);
        for(int i = 0; i < item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top; i++)
        { 
            RECT temp;
            int r,g,b;
            r = int(r1 + double(i * (r2-r1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            g = int(g1 + double(i * (g2-g1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            b = int(b1 + double(i * (b2-b1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r, g, b));
            temp.left = 0;
            temp.top = i;
            temp.right = item->rc.right-item->rc.left;
            temp.bottom = i + 1; 
            FillRect(hdcmem, &temp, Brush);
            DeleteObject(Brush);
        }
        HBRUSH pattern = CreatePatternBrush(hbitmap);

        DeleteDC(hdcmem);
        DeleteObject(Brush);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);

        return pattern;
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBRUSH defaultbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH hotbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH selectbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_uncheckedbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_checkedbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_hotbrush1 = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_hotbrush2 = NULL;
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                HWND Exit_Button = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"EXIT", 
                                                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                                                        50, 50, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_EXIT_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
                if(Exit_Button == NULL)
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Button Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                HWND Pushlike_Button = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"PUSH ME!", 
                                                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE, 
                                                        200, 50, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
                if(Pushlike_Button == NULL)
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Button Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
            }
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            {
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case IDC_EXIT_BUTTON:
                            {
                                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                            }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR some_item = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

            if (some_item->idFrom == IDC_EXIT_BUTTON && some_item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)some_item;

                if (item->uItemState & CDIS_SELECTED)
                {
                    //Select our color when the button is selected
                    if (selectbrush == NULL)
                        selectbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(180, 0, 0), RGB(255, 180, 0), item);

                    //Create pen for button border
                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    //Select our brush into hDC
                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, selectbrush);

                    //If you want rounded button, then use this, otherwise use FillRect().
                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                    //Clean up
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    //Now, I don't want to do anything else myself (draw text) so I use this value for return:
                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    //Let's say I wanted to draw text and stuff, then I would have to do it before return with
                    //DrawText() or other function and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT) //Our mouse is over the button
                    {
                        //Select our color when the mouse hovers our button
                        if (hotbrush == NULL)
                            hotbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 230, 0), RGB(245, 0, 0), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, hotbrush);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }

                    //Select our color when our button is doing nothing
                    if (defaultbrush == NULL)
                        defaultbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 180, 0), RGB(180, 0, 0), item);

                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, defaultbrush);

                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
            }
            else if (some_item->idFrom == IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON && some_item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)some_item;

                if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, some_item->idFrom))
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
                    {

                        if (push_hotbrush1 == NULL)
                            push_hotbrush1 = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(0, 0, 245), RGB(0, 230, 255), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_hotbrush1);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }


                    if (push_checkedbrush == NULL)
                        push_checkedbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(0, 0, 180), RGB(0, 222, 200), item);


                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));


                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_checkedbrush);


                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);


                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);


                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
                    {
                        if (push_hotbrush2 == NULL)
                            push_hotbrush2 = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 230, 0), RGB(245, 0, 0), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_hotbrush2);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }

                    if (push_uncheckedbrush == NULL)
                        push_uncheckedbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 180, 0), RGB(180, 0, 0), item);

                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, defaultbrush);

                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
            }
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        }
        break;
        case WM_CTLCOLORBTN: //In order to make those edges invisble when we use RoundRect(),
            {                //we make the color of our button's background match window's background
                return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
            }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                DeleteObject(defaultbrush);
                DeleteObject(selectbrush);
                DeleteObject(hotbrush);
                DeleteObject(push_checkedbrush);
                DeleteObject(push_hotbrush1);
                DeleteObject(push_hotbrush2);
                DeleteObject(push_uncheckedbrush);
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    const wchar_t ClassName[] = L"Main_Window";

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = MainWindow;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, ClassName, L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 368, 248, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.message;
}
```

Comment: That looks very nice, +1 from me. I think that OP now has enough information to solve his problem successfully.

Comment: Thank you!  I can only choose one to have answered my question, but AlwaysLearningNewStuff would be second.

Comment: _you must catch NM_CUSTOMDRAW_ ... It's not the only way, you can also create an owner-draw button with `BS_OWNERDRAW` style.

Comment: Using Code::Blocks 17.02 with gcc compiler on Windows 7, I had to #define _WIN32_IE 0x0700 before including windows.h. I also created a resource.rc file and added 1 24 "winxp.manifest" to the resource.rc file.  I created a manifest file and named it winxp.manifest. I included both of these new files to the code::blocks project.   After taking those steps the colors displayed perfectly. Thank you FrogTheFrog

Comment: BS_GROUPBOX buttons don't appear to support NM_CUSTOMDRAW (tested on Windows 10 2004 and Windows 11 21H2).

Answer (score 11):

I do not remember the link for the original code, but code bellow helped me in the past to solve the problem you currently face.

Notice that it doesn't have resource file, as you have requested, and is in plain Win32 API.

Study it carefully, everything is commented by the original author.

Hopefully it will help you, as it helped me in the past.

If you have any questions, ask, I will try to answer them.

There are 4 ways, as far as I know, to change the color of the button:

1. *Owner draw* ( obvious solution ).
2. *Custom draw* ( in my opinion the best solution ).
3. *Subclassing* the control ( I do not like it, but it is possible ).
4. Use *bitmaps* as your buttons background.
5. Handling `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` :

> From MSDN :
>
> only **owner-drawn** buttons respond to the parent window processing this
>   message.

*Emphasis is mine.* If you plan to use this option read the [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) carefully.

Code bellow demonstrates cases 1, 2 and 4.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' \
    publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

ATOM RegisterWndClass(HINSTANCE hInst);

BOOL CreateMainWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HINSTANCE hInst;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine, 
    int nCmdShow)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex = {0};
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC  = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_USEREX_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES |
                  ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES | 
                  ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS;

    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    MSG msg;

    hInst = hInstance;

    if (!RegisterWndClass(hInstance))
       return NULL;

    if (!CreateMainWnd(hInstance, nCmdShow))
       return NULL;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
};

ATOM RegisterWndClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{

    WNDCLASS wndClass = {0};
    wndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;

    return RegisterClass(&wndClass);
 }

BOOL CreateMainWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"MainClass", L"Buttons sample",
         WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - 115,
         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - 50,
         230, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Owner draw button

            CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | 
                BS_OWNERDRAW, 10, 10, 60, 30, hWnd, 
                (HMENU)10001, hInst, NULL);

            // Custom draw button

            CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 80, 
                10, 60, 30, hWnd, (HMENU)10002, hInst, NULL);

            // Bitmap button

            HWND hBitmapButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE 
                | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_BITMAP,
                150, 10, 60, 30, hWnd,
                (HMENU)10003, hInst, NULL);

            HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

            HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

            hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 55, 25);

            SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

            SetDCBrushColor(hMemDC, RGB(0, 0, 255));

            RECT r = {0};
            r.left = 0;
            r.right = 55;
            r.top = 0;
            r.bottom = 25;

            FillRect(hMemDC, &r, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

            DeleteDC(hMemDC);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

            SendMessage(hBitmapButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, 
                (LPARAM)hBitmap);

            return 0;
        }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case 10001:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Owner draw button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        case 10002:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Custom draw button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        case 10003:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Bitmap button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    // Owner draw button

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        if (wParam == 10001)
        {
            LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

            SetDCBrushColor(lpDIS -> hDC, RGB(255, 0, 0));

            SelectObject(lpDIS -> hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

            RoundRect(lpDIS -> hDC, lpDIS -> rcItem.left, lpDIS -> rcItem.top,
                lpDIS -> rcItem.right, lpDIS -> rcItem.bottom, 5, 5);

            return TRUE;
        }
        break;

    // Custom draw button

    case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> code)
        {
        case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
            if (((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> idFrom == 10002)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpnmCD = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;

                switch (lpnmCD -> dwDrawStage)
                {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:

                    SetDCBrushColor(lpnmCD -> hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                    SetDCPenColor(lpnmCD -> hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                    SelectObject(lpnmCD -> hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
                    SelectObject(lpnmCD -> hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));

                    RoundRect(lpnmCD -> hdc, lpnmCD -> rc.left + 3, 
                        lpnmCD -> rc.top + 3, 
                        lpnmCD -> rc.right - 3, 
                        lpnmCD -> rc.bottom - 3, 5, 5);

                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hBitmap != NULL)
            DeleteObject((HBITMAP)hBitmap);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I learned from this code too :). I even created my own custom-drawing class, but in the end I had to create my own button. Still, how does Microsoft create that blue hi-light effect around the button? Path gradient?

Answer (score 7):

You can edit a button(which has the flag BS_OWNERDRAW) in the message WM_DRAWITEM on the DialogProc([MSDN About WM_DRAWITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), heres a simple example of how to draw a simple button:

```
LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT Item;
    Item = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, "Arial Black"));
    FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, CreateSolidBrush(0));
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(0));
    if (Item->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
    {
        SetTextColor(Item->hDC, 0);
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(0xFF00));
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0xFF00));
    }
    else
    {
        SetTextColor(Item->hDC, 0x00FF00);  
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0x00FF00));

    }
    SetBkMode(Item->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    RoundRect(Item->hDC, Item->rcItem.left, Item->rcItem.top, Item->rcItem.right, Item->rcItem.bottom, 20, 20);
    int len;
    len = GetWindowTextLength(Item->hwndItem);
    LPSTR lpBuff;
    lpBuff = new char[len+1];
    GetWindowTextA(Item->hwndItem, lpBuff, len+1);
    DrawTextA(Item->hDC, lpBuff, len, &Item->rcItem, DT_CENTER);
```

Comment: Hi. Your code works great, but we had a strange bug with it. The BRUSHes you create arent being freed and on our app, after many redraws of the window, each creating a new brush, it started to corrupt and all our drop down combo boxes had the number "6" where the down arrow should be.  IF we continued to use the app, eventually we needed a reboot of windows.  If we free the BRUSH allocations it's fine.  Might be down to how we are using it but it may be a problem not freeing the brushes.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [owner-drawn button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx#BS_OWNERDRAW) for that. For some reason, unlike other controls, regular buttons don't react to changes made in `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` message handler.

Comment: I have heard of this, but can you explain it more?

Comment: Well, I think I know enough about it.  Thank you!