# How to change the color button with subclassing?

Tags: c++, winapi, button, callback, subclassing

I want to implement in my code the subclassing and change the color of some push button.

I created the declaration for my push button:

```
OriginalProc =(WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(hWndButton, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)EditBoxProc);
```

Which message is responsible for the painting of button?

Thanks!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21501c6c-f45e-48bc-8680-cf6d11f349ef/button-background?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @Itay Avraham In my opinion, you should try overriding `WM_PAINT` in your subclass procedure, but there is a better way to change the color of a button. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745447/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-button-winapi-c?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks! I want to try implement subclassing.