# I lose the functionality of button when I changes him background

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing, wm-paint

I tried every source to replace the background of button by implementation subclassing.

When I change the background, i got a square shape and impossible to click it.
somebody can share a good tutorial or sample of code?

anyway, 
this is my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DrawPushButton(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC          hdcMem;
HBITMAP      hbmMem;
HANDLE       hnd;
PAINTSTRUCT  ps;
HDC          hdc;

int win_width=100;
int win_height=50;
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, win_width, win_height);
        hnd   = SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, win_width, win_height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    return CallWindowProc (OldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

edit:
i added the BS_OWNERDRAW windows style to the button:

```
HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL,L"BUTTON",L"OK",WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON|BS_OWNERDRAW,50,220,100,24,hWnd,(HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
```

and i changed the callback,but WM_DRAWITEM didn't call:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DrawPushButton(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            TextOut(hdc,0,0,L"itay",4);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To custom draw a button, you need to give it the `BS_OWNERDRAW` window style and then handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message.

Comment: You don't think you should be deleting the DC and Bitmap that you're creating *every time the button paints* ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i added the BS_OWNERDRAW but when i debugging the program, WM_DRAWITEM didn't call. see my comment above.

Comment: @ItayAvraham: if you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923.aspx), `WM_DRAWITEM` will be sent to the button's parent window, not to the button's window.

Comment: @ItayAvraham: Why go through so much pain to change the background of the button? You can achieve this without subclassing. In my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745447/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-button-winapi-c?rq=1) you can see all the options to change the buttons background, and an implementation of some of them. Hopefully this will help you. Best regards and Marry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 'good' code, though it is functional - you should probably, as mentioned, be using BS_OWNERDRAW style and handle the drawing in the wndproc of the dialog/window that contains the button. I've chosen to paste an old example I have that approaches it in the same manner you have. You have to do *all* of the painting yourself. However, you do have the chance to respond to the WM_TIMER message that a button gets that makes it throb or pulsate. (not sure if you get a chance to do so if you only do the drawing from the dialog/window's WindowProc)

I've also chosen to use a superseded method of sub-classing, for the sake of simplicity. Since version 6 of the common controls, you should instead use SetWindowSubclass (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx)

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK btnProc(HWND btnWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    long oldWndProc;
    int i;
    oldWndProc = GetWindowLong(btnWnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                HDC hdc;
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                RECT mRect;
                HBRUSH mBrush;

                hdc = BeginPaint(btnWnd, &ps);
                mBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(100, 147, 111));
                GetClientRect(btnWnd, &mRect);
                FillRect(hdc, &mRect, mBrush);
                DeleteObject(mBrush);

                EndPaint(btnWnd, &ps);
            }
            return 0;
    }
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)oldWndProc, btnWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


void onCommand(HWND hwndDlg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDC_BUTTON1:
        MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        break;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND btnWnd;
            long oldBtnProc;
            btnWnd = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_BUTTON1);
            oldBtnProc = GetWindowLong(btnWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
            SetWindowLong(btnWnd, GWL_USERDATA, oldBtnProc);
            SetWindowLong(btnWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)btnProc);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            onCommand(hwndDlg, wParam, lParam);
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

**resource.h**

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#define DLG_MAIN                                100
#define IDC_BUTTON1                             1000
```

**resource.rc**

```
// Generated by ResEdit 1.5.11
// Copyright (C) 2006-2012
// http://www.resedit.net

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

//
// Dialog resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1", IDC_BUTTON1, 7, 7, 50, 14
}

//
// Manifest resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
1                  RT_MANIFEST    ".\\manifest.xml"
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```