# Background color of the button is not changed by WM_CTLCOLORBTN

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi

I try to change the default color of the button in my UI.

Here is my CallBacl function

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case FILE_MENU_NEW:
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        if (hEdit == (HWND)lp)
        {
            HDC hdcEdit = (HDC)wp;
            SetTextColor(hdcEdit, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetBkColor(hdcEdit, RGB(48, 56, 66));
            return (INT_PTR)hBrush1;
        }
    }

    case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
    {
        if (hButton_ok == (HWND)lp)
        {
            HDC hdcButton_ok = (HDC)wp;
            SetTextColor(hdcButton_ok, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetBkColor(hdcButton_ok, RGB(87, 102, 110));
            return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
        }
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

Now case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT changes the background color of my text input dialog correctly,
Why is then WM_CTLCOLORBTN fails?

Comment: What is style of button. Documentation says:

By default, the DefWindowProc function selects the default system colors for the button. Buttons with the BS_PUSHBUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, or BS_PUSHLIKE styles do not use the returned brush. Buttons with these styles are always drawn with the default system colors. Drawing push buttons requires several different brushes-face, highlight, and shadow-but the WM_CTLCOLORBTN message allows only one brush to be returned. To provide a custom appearance for push buttons, use an owner-drawn button.

Comment: Thanks! The style of button... Hmm. Here is the function creating it:  ```  hButton_ok = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Ok", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
  20, 235, 80, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)CHANGE_TITLE, NULL, NULL); ```  That is the function creating the button. Do you by chance now where I can find some minimal short example with the code creating owner-drawn button?

Comment: If your button is using visual styles it won't send `WM_CTLCOLORBTN`, since the rendering is handled entirely by the style.

Comment: Ok, I changed  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |  to WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW . It changed the color of the button but the text disappeared. As far as I understand it will send only WM_DRAWITEM ? But nope. Just checked. It responds to WM_CTLCOLORBTN. But the text on the button disappeared!

Comment: Is there a way to change the background color and text color without resorting to the ultimate evel of BS_OWNERDRAW style?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [How can I change the background color of a button WinAPI C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745447/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-button-winapi-c)