# How to change background color of wizard setup buttons?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm making my own design for the Inno wizard, but I can't seem to find how to change the background color of the buttons (next/back/cancel).

Does anyone know?

I know it has to be in the `[Code]` section under `procedure InitializeWizard();`

And should look something like

```
WizardForm.NextButton.Color := $464646;
```

But obviously this one doesn't work, hence I'm looking for any suggestions. And please don't recommend plugins, not going to use any plugins. My style looks the way I wanted it to look aside from the buttons.

Comment: That would be difficult even [with full access to WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18745447/850848), let only in Inno Setup. Buttons have complex style, they are not painted in a solid color (well they are in Windows 10, but that changes with every Windows version).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in vanilla Inno Setup.

In Windows drawing buttons is a complex task because buttons typically contains several "layers" which are painted individually - like frame, shadows, body (not single color).

The easiest to achieve this is to write custom plugin for Inno Setup (either C/C++ or Delphi - based on your preferences) and use the WIndows API, however this requires some additional knowledge.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BS_OWNERDRAW for more info.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for this reply. I guess I'll leave them as they are for now. At least the rest of the design looks the way I wanted.